# VB .net Non-Generic Interface with generic property

Tags: .net, vb.net, interface

I have a non-generic interface with a Function that returns a generic class
like so (Simplified):

```
Public Interface Osci  
    Function GetSingleSampleset() As Trace  
End Interface

Public Class Trace(Of t)  
...  
End Class

Public Class VirtualOsci  
Implements Osci  
    Public Function GetSingleSampleset() As Trace(Of Byte) Implements Osci.GetSingleSampleset
    ...  
    return new Trace(of Byte)  
End Function
End Class
```

My Goal is to have the implementing class define which type to use for Trace as this is of no concern to the interface in my mind.
**Question: Is this doable without making the interface generic?**

Comment: Use a common base class for the trace?

Comment: Humm seems somewhat clunky (as in more of a workaround), but solves the problem alright. Thanks very much!